# Change filename for IFormFile before upload to azure blob storege

Tags: azure, .net-core, iformfile

I am trying change filename for IFormFile before uploading it to azure blob storage but my current solution is not working

```
 public async Task<ExecuteResult> UploadAsync(string name, IFormFile file, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
          using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine("", name), FileMode.Create))
          {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
          }

        BlobClient client = _client.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);

        await using (Stream? data = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            await client.UploadAsync(data, true, cancellationToken);
        }
            return ExecuteResult.Success();
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
            when (ex.ErrorCode == BlobErrorCode.BlobAlreadyExists)
        {
            await UploadFileAsync(file, cancellationToken);

            return ExecuteResult.Success();
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            return ExecuteResult.Fail(new Error($"Unhandled Exception. ID: {ex.StackTrace} - Message: {ex.Message}", ""));
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it ?

**SOLUTION**

The problem is my misunderstanding of the file upload, if you are interested in saving the file under a different name you should put it in the line

```
                BlobClient client = _client.GetBlobClient($"{name}{format}");
```

**Complete solution**

```
public async Task<ExecuteResult> UploadAsync(string name, IFormFile file, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            string format = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

            BlobClient client = _client.GetBlobClient($"{name}{format}");

            await using (Stream? data = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                await client.UploadAsync(data, true, new CancellationToken());
            }

            return ExecuteResult.Success();
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            return ExecuteResult.Fail(new Error($"Unhandled Exception. ID: {ex.StackTrace} - Message: {ex.Message}", ""));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you change the solution part, to add it as a proper Answer below (and accept your own answer as an answer whenever you are able to?). Glad you managed to solve it!

Comment: You just posted this within the past 24 hours, and it already helped me out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The problem is my misunderstanding of the file upload, if you are interested in saving the file under a different name you should put it in the line

```
            BlobClient client = _client.GetBlobClient($"{name}{format}");
```

**Complete solution**

```
 public async Task<ExecuteResult> UploadAsync(string name, IFormFile file, 
  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        string format = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        BlobClient client = _client.GetBlobClient($"{name}{format}");

        await using (Stream? data = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            await client.UploadAsync(data, true, new CancellationToken());
        }

        return ExecuteResult.Success();
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException ex)
    {
        return ExecuteResult.Fail(new Error($"Unhandled Exception. ID: {ex.StackTrace} - Message: {ex.Message}", ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify the name of the file to create a sub directory in a blob container, you can do as follows:

```
public async Task<BlobResponseDto> UploadWithPrefixAsync(IFormFile blob, string prefix)
    {
        // Create new upload response object that we can return to the requesting method
        BlobResponseDto response = new BlobResponseDto();

        // Get a reference to a container named in appsettings.json and then create it
        BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(_storageConnectionString, _storageContainerName);
        //await container.CreateAsync();
        try
        {

            // Get a reference to the blob just uploaded from the API in a container from configuration settings
            BlobClient client = container.GetBlobClient($"{prefix}" + blob.FileName);

            // Open a stream for the file we want to upload
            await using (Stream? data = blob.OpenReadStream())
            {
                // Upload the file async
                await client.UploadAsync(data);
            }

            // Everything is OK and file got uploaded
            response.Status = $"File {blob.FileName} Uploaded Successfully";
            response.Error = false;
            response.Blob.Uri = client.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            response.Blob.Name = client.Name;

        }
        // If the file already exists, we catch the exception and do not upload it
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
           when (ex.ErrorCode == BlobErrorCode.BlobAlreadyExists)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"File with name {blob.FileName} already exists in container. Set another name to store the file in the container: '{_storageContainerName}.'");
            response.Status = $"File with name {blob.FileName} already exists. Please use another name to store your file.";
            response.Error = true;
            return response;
        }
        // If we get an unexpected error, we catch it here and return the error message
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            // Log error to console and create a new response we can return to the requesting method
            _logger.LogError($"Unhandled Exception. ID: {ex.StackTrace} - Message: {ex.Message}");
            response.Status = $"Unexpected error: {ex.StackTrace}. Check log with StackTrace ID.";
            response.Error = true;
            return response;
        }

        // Return the BlobUploadResponse object
        return response;
    }
```

My inspiration for this solution came after reading [this](https://blog.christian-schou.dk/how-to-use-azure-blob-storage-with-asp-net-core/) great article of Christian Schou.

Happy coding!